# How to play actions in a threejs object, loaded with useGLTF and showed with react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm loading an object using useGLTF (react three fiber)

I'm showing it with react three fiber

It's showing ok, but I don't know how to animate the object, it's animations are defined in the file that I provide to useGLTF

Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/myoffice-3wpf4?file=/src/Components/MyOffice.js

Here's the project in GitHub: https://github.com/rafaelsoteldosilva/serenity

The .glb file is in public/studio.glb

If you load it to gltf viewer (https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) you can see that the animations are there

[image]

Besides, what do I have to do to make those animations play automatically?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 4):

After creating the model, I had to do the following:

```
    const { scene, animations } = useGLTF('/studio.glb');
    let mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(scene);
    animations.forEach((clip) => {
        const action = mixer.clipAction(clip);
        action.play();
    });
    useFrame((state, delta) => {
        mixer.update(delta);
    });
```

It animated the object

rafael

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the useAnimation hook from the Three Drei library. It makes it easier to play and load the animations.

This is my 3D cube that is playing an animation.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import { useGLTF, useAnimations } from "@react-three/drei";

export default function Model({ ...props }) {
  const group = useRef();

  const { scene, animations } = useGLTF("/gltf/cubes.gltf", true);
  const { actions, mixer } = useAnimations(animations, group);
  useEffect(() => {
    actions.Animation.play();
  }, [mixer]);

  return <primitive ref={group} object={scene} dispose={null} />;
}

useGLTF.preload("/gltf/cubes.gltf");
```

Make sure to create a hook useRef to talk with your loaded 3D object.
I had a problem with rendering animated .jsx 3D objects, they looked super glitchy. That's why i use  instead of the .jsx object now.